# Difference between Borel and sigma fields

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Can anyone give me explains to me what is the difference between the Borel field and the sigma field?
Definition of Sigma field with the uncountable sample space:

1. All subset of the sample space that can be obtained by countable many intersections and unions of the interval of the form [x1,x2] with x1 <= x2
   Definition of Borel field with the uncountable sample space:
2. All subset of the sample space that can be obtained by countable many intersections and unions of open intervals of the form (a,b) with a <= b.

From here, isn't it the difference between them is just from closed and open forms? Then, why we need Borel field? And, why it's important?

Given the example of sample space: [0,1], can someone construct an example of sigma field and borel field?

Comment: Borel $\sigma$-field is the smallest $\sigma$-field that contains all open sets. $\sigma$-field is just a collection of subsets that meet the conditions you've listed

Comment: @MoneyBall Sorry. I still don't understand the difference between them. Do you mind to give some example?

Answer (score 0):

σ-field is a collection of sets that is closed under countable unions, countable intersections, and complements. Borel σ-field is the smallest σ-field that contains all open sets.

Given a space $\Omega = (0,1)$, $\mathcal{A} = \{ \Omega, \emptyset\}$ is trivially a $\sigma$-field (the intersection is the empty set, union is $\Omega$, and both are complements of each other), but $\mathcal{A}$ is not a Borel $\sigma$-field since it doesn't contain any open sets in $\mathbf{R}$.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-field. The term "smallest" means that for any $\mathcal{S}$ that contains all open sets, then $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{S}$. In fact, we know there exists a smallest set since we can define $\mathcal{B} = \bigcap \mathcal{S_n}$, where $\mathcal{S}_n$ is a $\sigma$-field that contains all open sets.

Comment: But how do we claim that Borel sigma-field is the smallest sigma field? What makes it "smallest"?

Comment: Also why don't we want to come up with something called "Borel field"? Why is that important?

Comment: @YokJyeTang I don't understand what you mean by Borel field. Borel $\sigma$-field is important in measure theory and Lebesgue integration theory since we want to deal with sets that are measurable, and Borel $\sigma$-field contains pretty much all open sets you can think of. The sets that are not in Borel $\sigma$-field are often pathological and you often don't see them in practice.

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is Borel sigma-field. Do you mind explaining what does "B" represent in your latest comment?

Comment: @YokJyeTang $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field

Comment: So for your example, can I say that the Borel sigma-field B ={Ω,∅,(0,0.5),(0.5,1)}?

Comment: @YokJyeTang no. borel $\sigma$ field contains all open sets, you listed two. You can't write down Borel sigma field since it has infinitely many open sets.

Comment: But, if you say borel sigma-fiel contains all open sets, does the "all open sets" fall into the range of (0,1)?

Comment: And if Borel sigma-field is also a sigma field, the complement of (0,0.5) is [0.5,1). Isn't that {Ω,∅,(0,0.5),[0.5,1)} is a sigma field (correction of previous answer)? Sorry I think I still confuse with the construction of Borel sigma-field.

Comment: @YokJyeTang all open sets should be from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. What you wrote is a $\sigma$-field. You can find more about constructing borel sigma field here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405327/borel-sigma-algebra-construction

Comment: "all open sets should be from −∞ to ∞" vs "A  is not a Borel σ-field since it doesn't contain any open sets in Ω". Isn't your later statement sounds like A is a Borel sigma-field if it contains all open sets in the sample space? Then I'm not sure what you mean all open sets should be from -inf to inf.

Comment: @YokJyeTang I fixed the post. Borel sigma field resides in $\mathbf{R}^d$. The example I presented is to give you a simple example of what sigma algebra is.